# Does κατὰ specify the lower plane of the head?

Tags: 1-corinthians

### Does κατὰ specify the lower plane of the head?

[Reference Quote](http://biblehub.com/greek/2596.htm)
2596 katá (a preposition, governing two grammatical cases) – properly, "down from, i.e. **from a higher to a lower plane, with special reference to the terminus (end-point)**" (J. Thayer).

Looking at it as literal location

Could cause 1 Corinthians 11 to translate as the following:

> 4 Every man praying or prophesying having his head bent down disgraces his head. 5 But every woman praying or prophesying with her head not concealed (bent down hiding the face) disgraces her head, tis indeed one and the same as the raze. 6 For if a woman does not conceal and sheers, but if indecent for women to sheer or raze, conceal. 7 Man truly indeed should not hide the face of the head being the head image and glory of God; the woman tis but a glory of man. 8 indeed not tis man out from within a woman but woman out from within man; 9 and indeed man was not created through the woman, but woman through man. 10 Through this ought the woman to have authority upon the head through the angels. 11 However neither woman separate of man, neither man separate of woman within the Lord. 12 indeed just as the woman out from within the men in this and the man of through the woman; but the all out from within the God. 13 Out from within you yourselves decide: proper tis woman not concealing the face praying to the God? 14 or neither this nature teaches you: that a man if indeed has long hair to him tis infamy, 15 but if a woman has long hair, tis glory to her? Since the long hair in exchange for the veil *has been* given to her. 16 But if ones thinks friendly of strife, we are not practicing such, neither the churches of the God.

Comment: No. I'm afraid this is literally nonsense. Is there something here that hasn't been covered in one of the [several other Q&As on this passage](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5B1-corinthians%5D+head+is%3Aq)?

Comment: (-1) because of Occam's Razor.

Comment: @enegue If you have a concern about DV patterns or other usage on this site in general, please bring it up on [meta]. Comments scattered across questions on main is not the right place for that.

Comment: @Decrypted please rollback your question to its original form (as the moderator did yesterday) and post a new question instead of completely changing this one. There is an answer (upvoted) on the old question, and to completely change a question to something totally different is not how this site works.

Comment: Please do not change the question to a completely different question after there are answers addressing the original question. If you have a different question post a new question. Edits for clarity would have been fine, but not to make it a completely different question. (Note this does not apply to question closures which may be substantially rewritten.)

Answer (score 5):

No, this idea makes just as little sense in Greek as it would in English. Rather than talking about the 'lower plane of the head', modern English-speakers typically prefer to use the word *mouth*. The author of 1 Corinthians has this same preference, which he demonstrates in the subsequent letter:

> "Our **mouth (στόμα)** is open unto you, O Corinthians, our heart is enlarged" - 2 Corinthians 6:11

If the author intended to talk about covering mouths, then he would surely have used the common term for *mouth* and not invented a bizarre and abstract term not otherwise witnessed in history.

Additionally, 1 Corinthians 11:14-15 plainly discusses the use of *hair* as a covering, and so unless first century women had a habit of covering their mouths with hair, the plain reading of the text demonstrates that this is not a sensible reading.